# Is it possible to write assembly code in vb.net or C#?

Tags: .net, assembly

i know how to write MSIL code but out of curiosity i would like to know if there is a workaround to write assembly code. I can think of a way like writing the code in a string and passing it to a native windows api that executes and returns the result but not sure if this is real or even possible.

i would like to hear your opinions/suggestions.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assemble it from C#, and pass the generated machine code to a C function like this through P/Invoke.

```
int execute(char* machine_code)
{
     int(*fn)() = machine_code;
     return fn();
}
```

You'd need to worry about making sure that the memory region is executable, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible to write assembly code directly in C# or VB.Net.

The closest you can get to doing this is to separate the assembly code into a native DLL which exported C style function entry points.  Then PInvoke into those entry points from the C# / VB.Net application.

Another option is to use C++/CLI as it's possible to inline assembly into a C++/CLI project.

Comment: i understand, so the proper question to ask if it is possible to compile assembly code at runtime in C/C++ so thats if its possible then we can pinvoke a code string of assembly in to a native dll

Answer (score 1):

You can compile code using [fasm.dll](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=6239), and then use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` to make it callable.

Answer (score 1):

Another (more .NET) option here would be to write it in IL and compile either with ilasm, or something like MonoDevelop which has support for IL projects.

Comment: Of course the IL based assembly could then be merged into the C# assembly with [`al.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx). Manual editing of MSBuild files will be required...